# Counting Sort With Negative Integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I understand the counting sort algorithm for positive integers but how can i modify it to deal with negative integers?

Comment: You don't need to modify the algorithm - you just have to provide sufficient range in your array of counts.

Comment: If you refer to the page about [Counting Sort on GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/), if you simply align the count array's 0th index with your minimum value/lower bound, it will work just fine.

Comment: @PaulR how can I provide this range ?

Comment: Well if your range is M to P then your array size needs to be P - M + 1 and you need to offset your array indices by M.

Answer (score -1):

I have coded something here, it could be called a counting sort, I am making use of hash maps here .

So for this example, I am assuming my array to be like

```
int a[] = {-3,-1,2,4,-2,-2,5,6};
```

Now here is the flow of my algorithm:-

```
1. Declare a map - map<int, int> m; // it keeps the count of each array element.
2. Iterate through your array and keep making a count increment.
3. With this for loop keep track of minimum and maximum element present in the array.
4. Now start another loop from minimum number to maximum number and based on the count for that element, print it out.
```

Here is the working code for it:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a[] = {-3,-1,2,4,-2,-2,5,6};
   map<int, int> m;
   int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
   int min_num = INT_MAX;
   int max_num = INT_MIN;
   for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
      min_num = min(min_num, a[i]);
      max_num = max(max_num, a[i]);
      m[a[i]]++;
   }
   for(int i=min_num; i<=max_num; i++)
   {
      int count = m[i];
      if(count>0) 
      {
         for(int j=0; j<count; j++)
         {  
            cout<<i<<" ";
         }   
      }
   }
   cout<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps !